# Is there a more efficient way of creating a list based on an existing list and a lookup list?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have the following method that takes an extremely long time to run and would love some help to make it run faster and or be more efficient.

The main responsibility of the method is to take a list of data points created from a CSV file, map the `Name` property of the file datapoints to the to the `HistorianTagname` property in a list of tagnames by the `DataLoggerTagname` property and create a resulting list from the mapping.  If the mapping does not exist, the file datapoint is ignored.

I know it that was long-winded, but I hope it makes sense.  It may be easier just to look at the method:

```
    private IEnumerable<DataPoint> GetHistorianDatapoints(IEnumerable<DataPoint> fileDatapoints, IEnumerable<Tagname> historianTagnames)
    {
        /**
         ** REFACTOR THIS 
         **/

        foreach (var fileDatapoint in fileDatapoints)
        {
            var historianTagname = historianTagnames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DataLoggerTagname.Equals(fileDatapoint.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (historianTagname != null)
            {
                var historianDatapoint = new DataPoint();

                historianDatapoint.Name = historianTagname.HistorianTagname;
                historianDatapoint.Date = fileDatapoint.Date;
                historianDatapoint.Value = fileDatapoint.Value;

                yield return historianDatapoint;
            }
        }
    }
```

Notes:
I have complete control of classes and methods of mapping, so if I am doing something fundamentally wrong.  I would love to know!

Thanks!

Comment: use a dictonary for historianTagnames if there are a lot of tagnames. You are basically going over them again and again and dictrionary will save some of the computation

Comment: Have you considered storing your historianTagNames into a `Dictionary<string,Tagname> dic = new Dictionary<string, Tagname>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` Then just access the historianTagName with `dic['yourkey']` That should give you better performance I believe ?

Comment: @AdolfoPerez: +1 good idea with passing StringComparer as EqualityComparer to Dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my proposition:

```
private IEnumerable<DataPoint> GetHistorianDatapoints(IEnumerable<DataPoint> fileDatapoints, IEnumerable<Tagname> historianTagnames)
{
    var tagNameDictionary = historianTagnames.ToDictionary(t => t.DataLoggerTagname, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    foreach (var fileDatapoint in fileDatapoints)
    {                
        if (tagNameDictionary.ContainsKey(fileDatapoint.Name))
        {
            var historianTagname = tagNameDictionary[fileDatapoint.Name];
            var historianDatapoint = new DataPoint();

            historianDatapoint.Name = historianTagname.HistorianTagname;
            historianDatapoint.Date = fileDatapoint.Date;
            historianDatapoint.Value = fileDatapoint.Value;

            yield return historianDatapoint;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really liked Adolfo Perez comment and updated the code - I think it's cleaner now.

Comment: Thanks for the complete code-sample.  Using the dictionary, the mapping is now practically instantaneous.  Thanks all who contributed!

Answer (score 4):

I would start by fixing up:

```
var historianTagname = historianTagnames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DataLoggerTagname.Equals(fileDatapoint.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

That's a pretty expensive operation to run every iteration through this loop.

Answer (score 2):

Like **@Sheldon Warkentin** said `FirstOrDefault` is probably bottle neck of your function, i s better to create historianTagnames a `Dictionary` where Name is key, then in your function you can get value by key.

Something like bellow:

```
// this is passed to method
IDictionary<string, Tagname> historianTagnames;
// .. method body
var historianTagname = historianTagnames[fileDatapoint.Name];
```

ofcourse you need to add proper if's.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a `Dictionary<string, Tagname>` might perform better.

```
var historianDict = new Dictionary<string, Tagname>();
foreach (var tagName in historianTagnames) {
    historianDict[tagName.DataLoggerTagname.ToLowerInvariant()] = tagName;
}

foreach (var fileDatapoint in fileDatapoints) {
    if (historianDict.ContainsKey(fileDatapoint.Name.ToLowerInvariant()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```